# How to get the set of dates between date_from and date_to

Tags: sql

I have a table:

| good_id | from_date | to_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-03 |

I want to get a data table like this:

| good_id | all_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 |
| 1 | 2021-10-02 |
| 1 | 2021-10-03 |

I tried using Cross Join with an all_date table containing all the dates in October. but it didn't work. Do you have any ideas for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the solution for your problem typically is done in the other direction.  We usually start with a *calendar* table looking like:

```
dates (dt)
----------
2021-10-01
2021-10-02
2021-10-03
```

And then left join this table to your table containing the date ranges, e.g.

```sql
SELECT d.dt
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON d.dt BETWEEN t.from_date AND t.to_date;
```

Note that SQL usually is not so good as generating new data.  Mainly, it is used for extracting or altering data which already exists.  Using a calendar table as shown above is a standard way of handling your problem.  In practice, you might include more dates to cover whatever data you expect in your table.